# Define $h(x)=f(x)$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$; $h(x)=-f(x)$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Define $h(x)=f(x)$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$; $h(x)=-f(x)$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Given that $h(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, can I conclude that $[h(x)]^2$ is differentiable at $x=0$? I think the given condition requires $f(0)=0$ but don't know what to proceed with that...

Comment: $|h(x)|^2=h(x)^2=f(x)^2$ for every $x$ but as the answer below shows,this and $f(x)=0$ are insufficient to imply a derivative for $f^2$ at $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $f(x)=\mid x\mid^{1/4}$, $h$ is continuous at 0 but $h^2$ is not differentiable at 0.